# Python filtering a list, lower- and uppercase aren't important

Tags: python, list, filter, lowercase

I need to write a function in Python which requires 2 paramethers: a list and a string. The function must return with a list of those products which exists in the list.
Here is an example:

```
products = ['Chocolat', 'peanutbutter','sugar', 'Chocolatcream']
result = myfunction(products, 'chocolate')
```

-> it should be `['Chocolat', 'Chocolatecream']`
...and so on. The important thing is that lower- and uppercase aren't important!

Here is my code, what I wrote...:

```
def myfunction(products, product):
    list = products

    trueorfalse =[ product.lower() in x for x in [element.lower() for element in list]]
    eempty = []
    for i in trueorfalse:
        if trueorfalse[i] == True:
            eempty.append(products[i])
            ++i
    return eempty   

products = ['Csokolade', 'MogyoroVAJ', 'valami', 'ize', 'kutyakaja', 'vajaskenyer']
res=myfunction(products,'VAJ')
print(res)
```

And I expect `['MogyoroVAJ', 'vajaskenyer']` as a result, but I got `['MogyoroVAJ', 'MogyoroVAJ']`

I have no idea how can I fix it, I tried many-many different solutions but there's some kind of different problem every time.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: does `product` need to be in the same order in `products`? So if `product = 'vaj'` then would you like to return `'vja'` also?

Comment: Have a look at regex to find patterns in strings.

Answer (score 1):

```
def myfunction(products, product):


    emptylist = []
    for items in products:

        if product.lower() in items.lower():
            emptylist.append(items)


    return emptylist

products = ['Csokolade', 'MogyoroVAJ', 'valami', 'ize', 'kutyakaja', 'vajaskenyer']
res = myfunction(products,'VAJ')
print(res)
```

However, keep in mind:

```
products = ['Chocolat', 'peanutbutter','sugar', 'Chocolatcream']
result = myfunction(products, 'chocolate')
```

may not work. 
You need to have an exact substring.

```
products = ['Chocolat', 'peanutbutter','sugar', 'Chocolatcream']
result = myfunction(products, 'chocolat')
```

will return the right list.

You could do:

```
def myfunction(products, product):

    product = product[0:len(product)-1]
    print(product)
    emptylist = []
    for items in products:

        if product.lower() in items.lower():
            emptylist.append(items)

    return emptylist

products = ['Chocolat', 'peanutbutter','sugar', 'Chocolatcream']

result = myfunction(products, 'chocolate')

print(result)
```

But keep in mind. This searches a match for all characters of a string except the last letter in the string. This could lead to potential problems in `res = myfunction(products,'VAJ')` since, the function will then look for an occurence of the substring `va`. So literally any string that contains a `va` even unintentionally will be returned. `['MogyoroVAJ', 'valami', 'vajaskenyer']` will be returned when you call

```
products = ['Csokolade', 'MogyoroVAJ', 'valami', 'ize', 'kutyakaja', 'vajaskenyer']

result = myfunction(products, 'VAJ') using the above modified code.
```

Comment: Thank you so much, 'chocolate' as an example was just an uncorrect typing, it should've been 'chocolat'. Many thanks, it's totally clear now!

Comment: Choose this as the accepted answer then, hit the TICK mark if it helped you accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 0):

A list comprehension could be used to do this as follows:

```
def myfunction(products, search):
    return [product for product in products if search.lower() in product.lower()]

products = ['Chocolat', 'peanutbutter', 'sugar', 'Chocolatcream']
print myfunction(products, 'chocolat')

products = ['Csokolade', 'MogyoroVAJ', 'valami', 'ize', 'kutyakaja', 'vajaskenyer']
print myfunction(products,'VAJ')
```

This would display:

```
['Chocolat', 'Chocolatcream']
['MogyoroVAJ', 'vajaskenyer']
```